# Why has the css for my tumblr answer posts stopped working?

Tags: html, css, tumblr, tumblr-themes

The css for my answer posts was working like the other posts before I added a specific block for the answer posts. However, this block did not start working until I added:

`.text blockquote { border: 3px solid #fff; padding: 0px 10px;}` 

to style the text post.

I am new to html/css coding and I do not know all the specific tumblr things so please excuse the messy layout and roundabout coding.

The url to my tumblr is: [ellenosaurus.tumblr.com](http://ellenosaurus.tumblr.com) so you can see the problem.

The whole code for my theme is here: http://pastebin.com/AJPab7BK

The html for my answer post is:

```
{block:Answer}
        <div class:"answer">
            <div class="asker">{Asker}</div> asked: <div class="question">{Question}</div>
            {Answerer}
            {Answer}
            {Replies}
        </div>
        {/block:Answer}
```

The css for my answer post is:

```
.answer {
        background: rgba(251, 230, 202, 1);
        margin: 40px auto;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 500px;
        border: 2px solid #fff;
    }
    .answer blockquote{
        border-left: 3px solid #fff;
        padding: 0px 10px;
    }
    .answer a {
        font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: rgb(52, 47, 20);
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .asker {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .question {
        font-weight: normal;
        display:block;
    }
```

Comment: your class in the answer div is wrong. it should be `=` not `:`

Comment: thanks I can't believe I didn't spot that!

Comment: So I fixed it and I tries to fix up the way the text looked but now two lots of the answer are coming up. Here is the new theme markup: http://pastebin.com/EdGnPTUn

Comment: Nevermind. The problem has stopped now. I'm not sure what I did but its ok now.